# prettify JSON output of active-model-serializer in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, active-model-serializers, awesomeprint

I am testing active-model-serializer output in the rails console and I am looking for a way to prettify the output. The the only solution I have found so far is:

```
ap JSON.parse(ProfileSerializer.new(p).to_json)
```

That seems like a roundabout approach. Is there a "better way"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(ProfileSerializer.new(p).serializable_hash)
```

That way you don't:

1. generate a JSON string, then
2. parse it back, then
3. output it

but just generate a prettified JSON string.

Comment: I am going to use this way for a situation where i need to add serialized object as json in a json which has some other data too, and which is being return as render i.e for json response. I don't know if this is a bad idea but it seems it will work :)